# Fetch the exact time a video was uploaded

Tags: python, youtube, youtube-api

I'm using the [Youtube API](http://gdata-python-client.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/pydocs/gdata.html) to search using a keyword query:

```
import gdata.youtube
import gdata.youtube.service

def youtube_query(query_text, 
        max_results=50, 
        start_index=1, 
        racy='exclude',
        orderby='relevance'):
    client = gdata.youtube.service.YouTubeService()
    query = gdata.youtube.service.YouTubeVideoQuery()

    query.vq          = query_text
    query.max_results = max_results
    query.start_index = start_index
    query.racy        = racy
    #query.format = 5
    query.orderby     = orderby
    feed = client.YouTubeQuery(query)
    resultsCount = int(feed.total_results.text)
    entries = []

    try:
        while resultsCount > int(query.start_index):
            print repr(feed.entry)
            entries += feed.entry
            query.start_index = int(query.start_index) + int(query.max_results)
            feed = client.YouTubeQuery(query)
    except gdata.service.RequestError:
        #
        # Cannot request beyond 1000 items.
        #
        pass    
    return entries
```

Each entry is a [YoutubeVideoEntry](http://gdata-python-client.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/pydocs/gdata.youtube.html#YouTubeVideoEntry).

The *date* each video is uploaded should definitely be accessible, as it is displayed for every video:

[image]

I need the *time* as well.  Does anybody know if this can be done?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the `entry.published.text` attribute:

```
import datetime
import time

feed = client.YouTubeQuery(query)
for entry in feed.entry:
    _tmp = time.strptime(entry.published.text, '%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S.000Z')
    ptime = datetime.datetime(*_tmp[:6])
    print ptime
    print ptime.time()
```

Output:

```
2010-01-27 19:42:42
19:42:42
```

Answer (score 1):

You can also use the parse_date function in the iso8601 library, which will return a date object:

```
import iso8601
uploaded_time = iso8601.parse_date("2007-01-25T12:00:00Z")
print uploaded_time
```

Output:

```
datetime.datetime(2013, 8, 21, 20, 54, 34, tzinfo=<iso8601.iso8601.Utc object at 0x1045d7b10>)
```