# How to get the last 24 hours worth of videos from a specific channel?

Tags: python, youtube, youtube-api, gdata

There are solutions for retrieving the [last video a user uploaded](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8509332/how-to-get-id-of-lastest-uploaded-video-on-youtube-channel), but is there a way to actually query a YouTube channel to fetch the ID's of all the videos uploaded in the last 24 hours?

I am hoping that the YouTube has an API parameter for this, but I haven't been able to find one. If the ability to fetch such results is not possible, than my other solution was going to be to fetch the last 10 videos from a channel and see which ones of them have been uploaded within the last 24 hours.

Edit: Here is how I could get a users uploads, but I only want the ones within 24 hours:

```
def GetAndPrintUserUploads(username):
  yt_service = gdata.youtube.service.YouTubeService()
  uri = 'http://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/users/%s/uploads' % username
  PrintVideoFeed(yt_service.GetYouTubeVideoFeed(uri))
```

Comment: I have little knowledge of interacting with the Youtube API, but perhaps you'll be able to extract some kind of fix from this? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5684161/fetch-the-exact-time-a-video-was-uploaded

Comment: @AlexThornton Thanks, it look like I can get the entries from the code I posted and then check their times. I'm confused as to what this one part of the answer does though: `ptime = datetime.datetime(*_tmp[:6])` what is `*_tmp[:6]` doing?

Comment: Don't worry about that. Because I imagine that the Youtube API stores time in a different format, `_tmp` parses it into a format understandable by `datetime`, and the list slicing just grabs the datetime output that they want, ie. the date and time to the nearest second, which is all you should need for your code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using the latest Data API do a [search.list call](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/search/list) setting [type](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/search/list#type) = video, [channelId](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/search/list#channelId) and [publishedAfter](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/search/list#publishedAfter).

That will give you the videos uploaded to that channel in the specified time.

Comment: I've accepted your answer, and will attempt to implement this, but some sample code would help the answer. Not the whole code of course, just a line or two showing how to use it.